# load multiple tables in one spreadsheet into R

Tags: r

I have an Excel worksheet containing multiple tables that I want to import into R (import as multiple data frame). I know how to do that if these tables are stored in different tabs, but the raw file that I'm using has several tables in one tab.

[Part view of my spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38871.png)

I'm wondering if it is possible to have R read each table into a separate data frame by a certain function. Say once R reads a blank row, it just stops and imports all above rows into one table, then restart the process to read the second table, for example. Or do I have to manually save each table into a separate tab/sheet to let R read them?

Note: I cannot use `nrow=n` in the `read.table` package as the row of each table might be changing. I need to find a more universal way to make the whole process automatic, regardless of the structure of each table.

Comment: Some of the Java based Excel packages have vectorized `startRow`, `startCol`, `endRow`, `endCol` arguments that allow you to specify distinct rectangular regions to read. XLConnect, for instance.

Comment: @joran Thank you! But the thing is the location of each table might be changed over time as the no. of row is not fixed. Actually each row is representing a date, so the table will be updated with more rows added in in weekly basis. Then how am I supposed to specify the startRow and endRow?

Comment: Frankly, it would probably be simpler to just read the whole thing into one data frame and then split it up in R by looking for empty rows.

Comment: @Joran thank you for the suggestion. I think I probably will go with your suggestion to load all tables into R first and then using string detect to split them out. thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you reliably have blank rows delimiting your sheets, you might try reading each tab in as a big table, then splitting it that way.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

# read the whole thing into a single file
wholeworksheet  <- read_excel('myfile.xlsx')

# find the blank rows
blankrows  <- data_frame(
    blanks = which(is.na(wholeworksheet[1]))
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
      dif = blanks - lag(blanks)
    , rownum = row_number()

    # maybe someone can suggest a better way to handle using dplyr::lag() 
    , startrow = ifelse(rownum == 1, 1, NA)
    , startrow = coalesce(ifelse(dif == 1, lag(startrow, default =1), lag(blanks + 1)), 1)
  )

# get the end rows of each table
endrows  <- blankrows %>% 
  group_by(startrow) %>% 
  summarize(
    endrow = min(blanks)
  )

# combine start and end rows into a single table
tableindex <- blankrows %>% 
  left_join(endrows, by = 'startrow') %>% 
  distinct(startrow, endrow)

# the last blank row is probably just before the last table in the sheet
if(nrow(wholeworksheet) > max(blankrows$blanks)) {

  lasttable  <- data_frame(startrow = max(blankrows$blanks) + 1, endrow = nrow(wholeworksheet))
  tableindex  <- tableindex %>% 
    bind_rows(lasttable)
}

# split your tables up into a list of tables 
alistoftables  <- map(1:nrow(tableindex), ~ wholeworksheet[tableindex$startrow[.x]:tableindex$endrow[.x] , ]  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you manually `copy/paste` each table into it's own tab and then export each tab into a CSV or TSV? That is what I would normally do.

If that is too much work, then @joran's suggestion will probably work. You could use `stringr::str_detect()` to identify when a column or row is empty or not empty and then plug that information into the `startRow`, `startCol`, `endRow`, `endCol` parameters.

Comment: yea, I think you're right. Probably read all tables into one file first in R and then detect empty row to split them is a better way. Thank you!