# Start reading an excel after empty line

Tags: r, excel

[image]I have several excel files I need to read, but in some of them the results start in row 41 in others in 48. Though all start after one single empty row. How can I write a code to read every file after this empty row?
here is an example: my data start from row 41. The name of the cell is the same, it's the position that changes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Skip all leading empty lines in read.csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26456814/skip-all-leading-empty-lines-in-read-csv)

Comment: @ConfusionMatrix It is an excel file, and I am guessing they have other table above lines 41, 48, which they want to avoid importing.

Comment: Could you provide the screenshot of an example excel sheet?

Comment: `read_excel` from the [readxl package](https://readxl.tidyverse.org/) has a `skip = ` argument which allows you to skip a specified number of lines before reading. If you use RStudio you can preview the sheet and edit the arguments before reading.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/47637812/680068

Comment: @neilfws yeah, that would be tedious when we have multiple excel files.

Comment: there is other info in the first 39 or 46 rows, but the common thing is that row 40 or 47 is always empty, so I wanted to say read after the empty row.

Comment: @neilfws thank you, but this won't help. I have tried that by naming what is the first row, but I want to have a script that works for both types of excel files.

Comment: @zx8754 I'm not suggesting RStudio preview for every file. Use it to get it right for one example of each 41/48 file, write code to automate the rest.

Comment: @neilfws I cannot use this as the number of rows that will be skipped varies from file to file and I want to have a universal code. The only common think for all files is that there is one single empty row in all before the row we want to read and that the first cell from where we want to start reading has the same name. Preview also, won't help, as we want to skip steps....